# how to add image inside canvas arc

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I want to add image inside arc but image should be moved with arc. Currently I have some code and it's working for repeat but when it put no-repeat argument then it gets blank inside arc.

Here is what I am looking for but the image is not centered properly: [Image is a wheel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmNPN.png).

Here is the code

```
canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.src = (window.location.origin + window.location.pathname) + 'assets/files/' + (wheel.logoURL);
            img.onload = function() {
                var pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, 50, 0, PI2, false);
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.stroke();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `pattern` is not a good tool to use in your case ... Instead:

1. Create a second canvas that holds your logo image cropped inside a circle.
2. Then `drawImage(logoCanvas,x,y)` the logo-canvas into your background image.

**Here's code to create a logo-canvas** where your logo image is cropped inside a circle. The `imgTargetX & imgTargetY` arguments let you specify which part of the original logo image that you want to appear at the center of the circle:

```
function createLogoCanvas(img,radius,imgTargetX,imgTargetY){
    var c=document.createElement('canvas');
    var cctx=c.getContext('2d');
    // resize the canvas to the diameter of the desired circle (2*radius)
    c.width=c.height=radius*2;
    // fill an arc with the specified radius
    cctx.beginPath();
    cctx.arc(c.width/2,c.height/2,radius,0,Math.PI*2);
    cctx.fill();
    // use compositing to draw the logo img only
    // inside the just-filled arc
    cctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-atop';
    // draw the image in the arc
    // imgTarget will be at the center of the arc
    cctx.drawImage(img,-imgTargetX+radius,-imgTargetY+radius);
    // reset compositing to default
    cctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-over';
    // return the logo-canvas
    return(c);
}
```

**And here's a demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var bk=new Image();
bk.onload=start;
bk.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/spinning%20wheel1.png";
var logo=new Image();
logo.onload=start;
logo.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/marioStanding.png";
var imgCount=2;
function start(){
    if(--imgCount>0){return;}

    cw=canvas.width=bk.width;
    ch=canvas.height=bk.height;

    // draw the background
    ctx.drawImage(bk,0,0);
    
    // create a logo-canvas containing the logo image in a circle
    var logoCanvas=createLogoCanvas(logo,50,60,45);
    
    // draw the logo-canvas on the background
    ctx.drawImage(logoCanvas,261,187);    
}

function createLogoCanvas(img,radius,imgTargetX,imgTargetY){
    var c=document.createElement('canvas');
    var cctx=c.getContext('2d');
    // resize the canvas to the diameter of the desired circle (2*radius)
    c.width=c.height=radius*2;
    // fill an arc with the specified radius
    cctx.beginPath();
    cctx.arc(c.width/2,c.height/2,radius,0,Math.PI*2);
    cctx.fill();
    // use compositing to draw the logo img only
    // inside the just-filled arc
    cctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-atop';
    // draw the image in the arc
    // imgTarget will be at the center of the arc
    cctx.drawImage(img,-imgTargetX+radius,-imgTargetY+radius);
    // reset compositing to default
    cctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-over';
    // return the logo-canvas
    return(c);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<h4>Background wheel plus logo-canvas<br>Logo-canvas is logo (Mario!) cropped inside a circle</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```